# How long does Temporal guarantee ID uniqueness?

Tags: temporal-workflow

From the [docs](https://docs.temporal.io/docs/learn-glossary#workflow-id):

> **Workflow Id**: A unique identifier for a Workflow Execution. Temporal guarantees the uniqueness of an Id within a namespace. An attempt to start a Workflow with a duplicate Id results in an already started error.

Assuming a reuse policy of Reject Duplicate:

Does temporal guarantee this uniqueness for the duration of the retention period or forever? Do archival settings affect this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uniqueness is guaranteed while a workflow is open and then after it is closed up to the retention period.

I filed a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/temporalio/temporal/issues/487) to separate out these two periods.